# Unblocked read from InputStream of a BlueToothSocket while checking connection of the socket

Tags: java, android, exception, bluetooth, inputstream

I am trying to write a thread which will do following stuffs:

1. read from inputstream;

2. some other routine;

3. if socket is closed, throw an exception.

The BlueTooth Socket and inputStream from the socket has been set up before this. The code is as following:

```
public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;

    while (true) {
        try {
            //if(mInputStream.available() > 0){        //-------- Line 1
            bytes = mInputStream.read(buffer);
            //}                                      //-------- Line 2

            //---------------------//
            // some other routines //
            //---------------------//

        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionLost();
            break;
        }               
    }
}
```

The problem is that the above code will hang at **mInputStream.read()** because of the blocking. However, if I uncomment Line 1 and Line 2, the **mInputStream.available()** function will not throw exception even if BlueToothSocket is closed. Is there any method either to unblock read function, or to throw an exception when available() is used and BlueTooth Socket is closed? Appreciate it!

Comment: Where does it say that `available()` should throw an exception if the stream is closed? Have you considered setting a read timeout? Not a real question.

Comment: @EJP ... please refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStream.html#available()

Comment: Exactly as I thought. You have misunderstood. You haven't closed the stream: ergo the method doesn't throw `IOException.` It isn't specified to throw `IOException` when the *peer* closes the *connection.* You haven't answered my question about setting a read timeout.

Comment: @EJP I am a bit confused. So, you do exactly mean It says that `available()` should throw an exception if the stream is closed? Other from that, if `IOException` is not thrown when peer closes the connection, `read()` also should not throw an `IOException` with the same description of `IOException` throwing. However, in fact, `read()` throws `IOException` in the code provided in the question. In addition, could you help to specify where to set up a read timeout?

Comment: No. `read()` returns -1 when the peer closes the connection. Read timeouts are set with the `setSoTimeout()` method.

Comment: @EJP hmm, `setSoTimeout()` is a good idea. However, `BluetoothSocket` class doesn't have such kind of method. There is another question with `read()`: When the peer closes the connection, I tested that the code in the question will enter catch exception section and do `connectionLost()`. Does it mean `read()` will throw an exception after returns -1? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems there is not an easy way to do unblocked read() and available() throwing is not working. The most convenient way to work this out is **to create another thread to do the other routines**. While leave this thread alone particularly for reading inputstream and checking inputstream status(exception thrown).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use:

```
private boolean receivedInTimelyManner(InputStream mInStream,
        int bytesToReceive, long timeoutMillis) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {

    long time = 0;
    while (mInStream.available() < bytesToReceive && time < timeoutMillis) {

        time+=5;
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }
    if (time == timeoutMillis) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Surround your read block with something like:

```
if receivedInTimelyManner(instream,bytes,timeout){
    read()
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Previously I was not familiar with thread, and thought creating thread could be resource consuming. That is why I wanted to combine different functions into one thread. Later I find that's not the case. So I think spliting input stream read and other functions into two thread might be more efficient. For example, in the suggested solution, the timeout blocks the rest of the functions when doing read(). But, the answer gives a good example on how to have some control on blocking codes. Thanks!